# preg_match() get the source link of image using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get the image link from the html content with preg_match() function.

I tried like this but not getting the correct source link.

```
$data = "<div class="poster">
<div class="pic">
<img class="xfieldimage img" src="https://bobtor.com/uploads/posts/2019-01/1546950927_mv5bnji5yta2mtetztmzny00odc5lwfimzctnme2owqwnwnkywm1xkeyxkfqcgdeqxvyntm3mdmymdq._v1_-1.jpg" alt="Song of Back and Neck 2018" title="Song of Back and Neck 2018">
</div>
</div>";

preg_match("'<img class=\"xfieldimage img\" src=\"(.*?)\" alt=\"(.*?)\" title=\"(.*?)\" />'si", $data, $movie_poster);

print_r($movie_poster);
```

Its not working.

Comment: PD of [Get img src with PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/10130858)

Answer (score 2):

[self-contained tags meme link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image = $xpath->query("//img[@class='xfieldimage img']")->item(0);
echo $image->getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: The reason your attempt doesn't work is because your regex is looking for `<img ... />` but your code contains `<img ...>`. This is one of many reasons a parser works better.

Comment: Getting blank nothing returned

Comment: Turn error reporting on I guess? I don't know otherwise because this should work as described. https://3v4l.org/qSLLC

Comment: There is many images in a single page. So I want to get the image source within
<div class="poster">
<div class="pic">


</div></div>

Comment: `//div[@class='poster']//div[@class='pic']//img[@class='xfieldimage img']`